# pydriveでListFileで条件指定する方法

Tags: python, google-drive-sdk, pydrive

Pythonにおいてpydriveを使用しており、ListFile()で自身がオーナー（作成者）であるファイルのみをリスト化したいです。

```
drive.ListFile({'q': 'title = "file1"'}).GetList()
```

などでtitleやIDでの検索はできましたが、ownersのdisplayNameやemailAddressでの条件指定の方法がわかりません。

```
GoogleDriveFile({'kind': 'drive#file', 'id': '89h43gqhogehoge','title':'file1,
'owners': [{'kind': 'drive#user', 'displayName': 'tarou','emailAddress': 'tarou.hoge@mail.com'}],
```

の様な構成で、このidやtitleではなくownersの中のemailAddress等で検索をかけるを教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @cubick [PyDrive](https://github.com/googleworkspace/PyDrive)はDrive API v2を使用するようですので、`google-drive-sdk`のタグの表示は問題ないと思いましたがいかがでしょうか。タグ情報を見ると、`GoogleのクラウドストレージであるGoogleDriveへの、SDK・API・Apps Scriptなどによるアクセスに関する質問に使います。`とあります。[Ref](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-drive-sdk/info)

Comment: @Tanaike おっしゃる通りタグ付けには問題ありませんので戻しておきました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: @cubick ご返事ならびに修正していただき有難うございます。

Answer (score 1):

`PyDrive`はDrive API v2を使用しているようですのでこれに注意する必要があります。このことを考慮して、下記に回答させていただきます。

> Q1: ListFile()で自身がオーナー（作成者）であるファイルのみをリスト化したい

回答: 自分のファイルのみをリストとして取得したい場合は、`q`の値として、`'me' in owners`を使用することができます。また、自分以外のユーザの場合は、`'### email address ###' in owners`を使用します。残念ながら、displayNameでの検索はできないようです。

> Q2: `GoogleDriveFile({'kind': 'drive#file', 'id': '89h43gqhogehoge','title':'file1,'owners': [{'kind': 'drive#user', 'displayName': 'tarou','emailAddress': 'tarou.hoge@mail.com'}],`の様な構成で、このidやtitleではなくownersの中のemailAddress等で検索をかけるを教えていただきたいです。

回答: Drive API v2では、`fields`を指定しない場合、全てのmetadataが返されます。もしも上記のように必要なmetadataのみを取得したい場合は、`fields`を使用する必要があります。上記の場合、`items(id,title,kind,owners(displayName,emailAddress,kind))`を`fields`として使用します。

上記を使用されているスクリプトに反映させると、下記のようになります。

#### 変更したスクリプト

```
drive.ListFile({'q': "'me' in owners", 'fields': 'items(id,title,kind,owners(displayName,emailAddress,kind))'}).GetList()
```

#### 参考:

- [PyDrive](https://github.com/googleworkspace/PyDrive)
- [Files: list of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)